# Why is intellij chewing up my computers processing power?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've got a Macbook pro with the following spec that is specially bought just so that my computer can breath a little easier when I'm coding.

- 16GB Ram
- 2.5GHz quad-core
- 512GB SSD
- OSX Yosemite
- Running Intellij 15.0.3

But every time I run Intellij the fan runs on full speed 80% of the time even when I'm just browsing the files and after sometime the file viewer scrolling become jerky and slow and I have to stop & start Intellij after the fan stops running. And when I run my test cases or my Scala application .. OMG! Intellij makes my computer sound like a vacuum cleaner and the sides of the laptop gets so hot that I can fry bacon on it.

What is Intellij doing behind that scene that is making my new macbook pro regret that I bought it to run intellij on.

How do I fix it because right now I have to restart intellij 3 times a day ? I just want to be able to compile, debug & get autocompletion on my Scala & Java code.

Comment: I have the same experience developing J2EE code at work (and at home).  IntelliJ needs a lot of memory to do its business.  This is likely the root cause.

Comment: I have a lower-spec Linux laptop and I do not have this problem. My fans only kick on during the indexing when I first load a project, or when I compile.

Comment: But guys it doesn't happen in Eclipse. I have to use Intellij because my company paid for it and it's company policy but everyone seems to complaint the same issue. Loud fans are ok but Intellij slows down so much ... and become jerky that I have to restart it. Every other application (chrome, Mysql workbench) works fine.

Comment: Either diagnose the problem yourself using a profiler (VisualVM) or just report an issue! https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: The fact is that a computer with i7-6700K would be far better, but what `Engineer Dollery` is saying is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Try refreshing caches and re-starting IntelliJ through:

```
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

menu and clicking "Invalidate and Restart".

Beware that your local history will be erased. IntelliJ will re-index the projects when started so it would take some time for the first time.

There's also a `Power Save` mode accessible from `File` menu which disables most checkers and reduces CPU consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You should try IntelliJ 2016.2. I think they fixed this problem.

I was having the same problem with my MBA and it was driving me nuts! Although I don't use pure IntelliJ, I use Android Studio, whose version 2.2.2 is based on IntelliJ 2016.1.

Today I tried the new Android Studio 2.3 (Alpha) which is based on IntelliJ 2016.2 and now I don't see (er, hear) my fans at full speed anymore! :) Actually, when compiling, the fans do run at full speed, but after some time with no load, the fans go back to normal speed as they were supposed to.

I hope it helps.